Infinite range slider input
I want to have the ability for a user to use a range slider to select an infinite (or limited) set of values.
My first thought was to have the slider update after each selection, as per https://svelte.dev/repl/5ac7a20ef7b34456933dad7bc0611dee?version=4.2.18 However, this isn't intuitive and if the user scrolls past the slider object, it has some strange behaviour.
Then I thought about a continuous dial like (https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-9539480-tuning-fm-radio-stations-on-receiver-by) but from a side view as I don't want a circular component. This led me to develop an implementation of that (https://jsfiddle.net/oytL0rbe/1/). However, this isn't necessarily intuitive to use, partly because it doesn't look like the dial, but mostly because it's a new component.
Has anyone else come across this usecase or have any ideas?

It depends on the context and use case, but have you considered having an input for manual input and buttons to increase or decrease the value? This is accessible, easy to understand and easy to implement. Having multiple buttons is possible like 1/-1, 10/-10, 100/-100 etc. for quickly changing the value.
